# Proper way to use subversion

Tags: svn

When using subversion should you get latest from the server before making a commit or should you commit and then deal with any conflicts then?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Get the latest, resolve conflicts, and then commit

Comment: So how do you merge them locally?

Comment: Yes, locally. If two text files are in conflict, svn will create a third file where all conflicts are indicated (it is a kind of diff-file). You are supposed to edit this third file (i.e. resolve the conflicts) and then commit it.

Comment: Use a diff tool with the svn client, in windows I find TortoiseSVN and WinMerge for diff / merge the best way to go.  There are similar tools available on other platforms.

Answer (score 4):

Update first, that way you can deal with the conflicts and commit when your happy with it.

Answer (score 3):

You should update from code control, merge any changes other developers have made with yours and resolve any conflicts, then run tests and commit.

It's best to ensure that code in the repository always builds and passes your tests, and this can't be guaranteed unless you do the update/merge before the commit.

If the update/merge/reconcile process takes a while, you should even update again before the commit to make sure nothing's changed while you were doing it.

Answer (score 2):

You should update you working copy and resolve all conflicts. 
Even more, will be better if you run some smoke on your project after resolving to make sure that merge does not break something.